# How to update android local sqlite database from web using internet connection?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have developed an educational android application. I have also developed a web application to insert questions on the web and download in android sqlite database. And also the test result is uploaded to the web. The application is working locally without internet when its database is updated.
**My Problem:** I want to update my android application's sqlite database from my website using internet and to upload test result after someone completed the test. So, give me information programmatilly as soon as possible to update my android app from my website and to upload test result from android app to my website. 
I will be highly thankful!

Answer (score 0):

That is not a good practice to change your local `sqlite` database from web directly. You need to store your activities status in an external database (probably on your web server) and let your android app talk to your server and ask for update or new results (preferably a `JSON` response) and let you app update your local database.

If you want to get notified if anything has changed on your server you can use `Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)` or you can write a `SyncAdapter` to poll the server periodically to get the latest changes.

But never try to update your local `sqlite` database from web!

Comment: Great Job, 100% fact, Thank you!